# How to use a column value as delimiter in spark sql substring?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do a substring option on a column with another column as a delimiter, the methods like substring_index() expects string value, could somebody suggest ?

Comment: Could you add your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[substring_index](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#substring_index(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) defines it as `substring_index(Column str, String delim, int count)`

So if you have a common delimiter in all the strings of that column as

```
+-------------+----+
|col1         |col2|
+-------------+----+
|a,b,c        |,   |
|d,e,f        |,   |
|Jonh,is,going|,   |
+-------------+----+
```

You can use the function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("splitted", substring_index(col("col1"), ",", 1))
```

which should give result as

```
+-------------+----+--------+
|col1         |col2|splitted|
+-------------+----+--------+
|a,b,c        |,   |a       |
|d,e,f        |,   |d       |
|Jonh,is,going|,   |Jonh    |
+-------------+----+--------+
```

**different splitting delimiter on different rows**

If you have different splitting delimiter on different rows as

```
+-------------+----+
|col1         |col2|
+-------------+----+
|a,b,c        |,   |
|d$e$f        |$   |
|jonh|is|going||   |
+-------------+----+
```

You can define [udf function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#udf(scala.Function0,%20scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag)) as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def subStringIndex = udf((string: String, delimiter: String) => string.substring(0, string.indexOf(delimiter)))
```

And call it using `.withColumn` api as

```
df.withColumn("splitted", subStringIndex(col("col1"), col("col2")))
```

the final output is

```
+-------------+----+--------+
|col1         |col2|splitted|
+-------------+----+--------+
|a,b,c        |,   |a       |
|d$e$f        |$   |d       |
|jonh|is|going||   |jonh    |
+-------------+----+--------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can try to invoke the related hive UDF with two different columns as parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you please elaborate ?

Comment: You can use the "callUDF" function the following way:
callUDF("substring_index", col("firstCol"), col("secondCol"), lit(1))